# pandas data frame not recognizing index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to python, and am trying to read in a single row of data to a data frame, and then index it by value to get occurrence counts for each value in the row. This is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
csv=pd.read_csv('filepath/data.csv', 'r', converters={'csv':str})
df=DataFrame(csv, columns=['data'], index=['0.0', '750.0'])
df
```

When I just view 'csv' after reading in, it looks like this:

```
0.0 750.0 750.0 750.0 750.0 750.0 750.0
```

When I attempt to input it to a data frame however, I get this result:

```
data
0.0   NaN
750.0 NaN
```

What I'm hoping to get:

```
data
0.0   1
750.0 6
```

Thanks in advance for any insight!

Comment: `df=DataFrame(csv, columns=['data'])` then do `df['data'].value_counts`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Wen! When I try that, I get this:                       
<bound method Series.value_counts of Series([], Name: data, dtype: float64)> Seems to be telling me my data is still float64, even though I imported it as a string...?

Comment: Then you need data.value_counts

Comment: @muddypaws The point was to call the function like this - `value_counts()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `read_csv` is designed for tabular data with multiple rows and columns: if your data file has only a single row of values, it is probably cleaner to read it directly using Python's `open()`. Once you have those results in a list, pandas `value_counts` method will give you the counts of each value in the list: e.g.

```
values = open('data.csv').read().split()
pd.Series(values).value_counts()
# 750.0    6
# 0.0      1
# dtype: int64
```